# protractor - browser.wait() promise is not working

Tags: javascript, protractor

I am trying to verify the url of the page using `brower.wait`. This function prints logs when promise is fulfilled by condition `EC.urlIs(expectedUrl)` with truthy, however, if `EC.urlIs(expectedUrl)` promise rejects then control doesn't go inside `then` hence doesn't print logs.

```
const temp = async (expectedUrl) => {
  await browser.wait(EC.urlIs(expectedUrl), 1000).then(async res => {
    log.info(`expected url: ${expectedUrl}`);
    log.info(`current url: ${await browser.getCurrentUrl()}`);
  });
};
```

what should i do to print logs in both condition? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
const temp = async (expectedUrl) => {
  await browser.wait(EC.urlIs(expectedUrl), 1000);
  let text = await browser.getCurrentUrl();
  log.info(`expected url: ${expectedUrl}`);
  log.info(`current url: ${text}`);
};
```

but make sure you call it with `await`

```
await temp('https://your.url');
```

Comment: I will try this. Thank you